# unknown modules in qt :qtwaylandcompositor

Tags: c++, qtwayland

I'm using qt to develop embedded-linux application having having multi-windows ,so it should use QtWayland to manage them,but now I have no idea to use QtWayland,searching results says i should add QT += qtwaylandcompositor in .pro file ,I did it ,but it occurs errors saying that Unknown modules in QT,I do know the modules locate in addons ,but don't know how to add it,please someone can give me a hand,

Thanks so much!
dreampeak

Comment: You should make an effort to clarify your question, show relevant sections of your .pro/.pri file(s), so the compilation/linker errors you have